# Visualize antenna radiation pattern

Tags: antenna, reference-materials

I am looking for a free tool or codebase to visualize 2d and 3d antenna radiation patterns, as in the picture below:

[image]

Bonus points if open source. My goal is to visualise common antenna patterns in 2d and 3d to gather physical intuition, see the comments below for more details.

[Image source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318366373_A_Slotted_Rectangular_Microstrip_Patch_Antenna_for_Wideband_Wireless_Applications)

Comment: "visualization" requires that there's data – in what shape is that data currently?

Comment: I do not have data currently, I was hoping to have some preexisting common examples, as in https://uk.mathworks.com/help/antenna/gs/antenna-radiation-patterns.html to play with.

Comment: I'm confused. What is it that you want to *achieve*?

Comment: If you know the pattern (as a formula or a data table) and just want to visualize it, there are several free software packages that can do that. If you want to solve Maxwell's equations to find the pattern for a given antenna shape, that's a much more difficult problem and I'm not aware of any free solution. (The paid solutions include Ansys HFSS and CST Microwave Studio)

Comment: ah! I'd say what you describe as out-of-question scope would actually make this question sensibly answerable.

Comment: @ThePhoton My need is probably closer to the first option you mention. Feel free to share some names that you would suggest.

Comment: @Rexcirus please edit your question ... add a link to the source of the diagrams

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=scilab+antenna+radiation+pattern&ia=web

Comment: A critical piece of information is the _frequency range_ of the antenna. Some programs like NEC are not suitable for simulation of common types of microwave and higher antennas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you are looking for a plotting program or antenna simulator.

**Antenna Simulator**
[4NEC2](https://www.qsl.net/4nec2/) is a free program that calculates antenna beampatterns and feedpoint impedance. 4NEC2 can produce 2D and 3D antenna beampatterns as shown below. 4NEC2 isn't the easiest program to figure out, but there are many examples which will help you understand the syntax of creating the antenna structure.

[image]
[From 4NEC2 examples](https://www.qsl.net/4nec2/).

**Graphing Programs**
There are any number of free programs that support 3D graphing representations. Python, gnuplot, R, Octave, ...